# No "store" menu option or "Windows Store" project type in Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking at all these tutorials on how to create a Windows 8 app, and everyone keeps telling me to click on the Store menu option to request a developers license, but there is no Store menu option. There is also no project type for "Windows Store". What the ??

Comment: I found out that in VS 2013 Preview you won't see the option to create store apps unless you have Windows 8.1 installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Store menu has moved. You can find it under `Project -> Store`

Also you need Windows 8 running on your machine to develop Windows Store Apps.

Comment: I am running Windows 8, and there is no Store menu option under Project. Come to find out you have to have Windows 8.1 Preview installed to see the Windows Store menu option in VS 2013 Preview.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Visual Studio ? If it is RC2, you can find it in Project menu.